# Prove sublevel set is closed

Tags: matrices, closed-graph

$$f(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}log(b_i-a_i^Tx)$$
$dom\ f_0={Ax<b}, where\ A\ is\ a\ m\ by\ n\ matrix\ with\ rows\ a_i^T$

How to prove that the sublevel sets of $f_0$ is closed?

Generally, for a given function, how to show its sublevel sets are closed or not?

Comment: Do you mean closed relative to the domain or closed relative to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Typically one appeals to continuity to show closure.

Comment: @copper.hat are you saying a continuous function always has its sublevel sets closed?

Comment: The sublevel sets are of the form $f^{-1} ((-\infty, \alpha])$ and since $(-\infty, \alpha]$ is closed, it follows that the sub level sets are closed if $f$ is continuous. Closed means closed relative to the domain in this case.